# TFS and Git - prevent linking work-items when merging

Tags: git, tfs, merge, tfs-workitem

I have two repos:

"Baseline" and "MyProject", where MyProject is a heavily-customized bespoke version of Baseline.

Using remotes, when I work on MyProject, I configure Baseline as "upstream" remote so I can pull development from the core team.

The problem: when I use “git merge upstream/dev” and commit a changeset with all the merged code from the Baseline into MyProject, I find out that redundant copies of the commit links have been added to all the work-items in the Baseline project.  I don't want the Baseline project's work-items to get marred by every branch every commit gets merged into.

Is there a way to make this work?  A way to say "only extract work-item links from merges when they're merged into Baseline repo's **dev** or **master**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to prevent links based during the merge action. This is by default. You may have to manually delete the links in workitem for your situation.